Servant client pagination
Given the following Servant API definition:
type API =
  "single-content" :> Get '[JSON] Int
    :<|> "contents" :> QueryParam "page" Int :> Get '[JSON] (Headers '[Header "Link" String] [Int])

The second endpoint is paginated, and contains a next Link header in the response if there are more elements.
I can generate client functions using servant-client:
paginatedClient :: Maybe Int -> ClientM (Headers '[Header "Link" String] [Int])
singleClient :: ClientM Int
singleClient :<|> paginatedClient = client (Proxy :: Proxy API)

I'm looking for a way to extend the client function for the paginated endpoint so that it automatically picks up the link from the response headers, call the next page, and accumulate the results.
Ideally, the type signature wouldn't change compared to the default client. It would be fine if the request would live in a different monad than ClientM.
I found some prior art and had some ideas, but nothing that brings me closer to my goal:

The closest match I found is in the servant-github package, which basically does exactly what I want, but it hasn't been updated for a while and is not compatible with recent versions of servant. I haven't found a way to migrate that functionality to the latest servant-client
There is this issue in the servant repo, which talks about pagination but not about corresponding client functionality. It also mentions the servant-pagination package, which also doesn't cover client functionality and uses a different approach to pagination.
servant-client supports client middleware, which makes intercepting requests possible, but it only gives access to the raw response, so there's no chance to know how to deserialize and accumulate the responses
I think hoistClient also doesn't work, because it's not possible to implement different behavior for the non-paginated case vs the paginated case. I might be missing something here, but as far as I understand it's not possible to change the behavior based on the a inside the monad.


Can you simply offer an unpaginated version of the endpoint? It sounds like this client isn't taking advantage of pagination anyway.

@DanielWagner good point, but unfortunately not. I left out two details in my description: I'm not controlling the server side, I'm only working on client bindings for the API. Plus, a future version of that would support client-side control of the pagination (like limiting the number of results) and/or streaming the results as they come in instead of accumulating them in a list.

Surely the fact that you want to put business logic into the fetch makes it obvious that in the long run automation can't help you here...?

@DanielWagner Following pagination links doesn't look a lot like business logic, sounds more like work for some decorator.

@danidiaz Choosing how many links deep to follow is the business logic bit. The answer is different for "limiting the number of results" and "streaming the results" (and, for that matter, different again for "fetch all results").

Besides the usual Servant packages and imports, this answer also depends on http-client.
This is a function that takes a URL string and a Servant client action, and overwrites the path (and query string) of all HTTP requests performed by the action with the URL parameter.
import Network.HTTP.Client.Internal qualified as Http

overrideUrl :: String -> ClientM a -> ClientM a
overrideUrl url action = do
    request <- Http.parseRequest url
    let transformClientRequest original = 
            original { 
                Http.path = request.path, 
                Http.queryString = request.queryString  
                }
        transformMakeClientRequest f baseUrl servantReq = do 
            httpReq <- f baseUrl servantReq 
            pure $ transformClientRequest httpReq
        transformClientEnv clientEnv = 
            clientEnv { 
                  makeClientRequest = 
                    transformMakeClientRequest clientEnv.makeClientRequest 
                }
    local transformClientEnv action   

It works by tweaking the values in the ClientEnv using local.
This is a function that takes a Servant client action that returns a monoidal value along with a "next page" link, and returns another action that collects all the results while following the links:
paginated :: 
    forall (s :: Symbol) rest a . Monoid a => 
    ClientM (Headers (Header s String ': rest) a) ->
    ClientM (Headers (Header s String ': rest) a)
paginated initial = do
    let go action acc = do
            r <- action
            let acc' = acc <> getResponse r
                HCons header _ = getHeadersHList r
            case header of 
                UndecodableHeader {} -> do
                    liftIO $ throwIO $ userError "undecodable header"
                MissingHeader -> do
                    pure $ r { getResponse = acc' }
                Header next -> do
                    go (overrideUrl next initial) acc'
    go initial mempty

paginated makes use of overrideUrl to go to a different link each time, while keeping the same request headers and other configuration.
The question now is how to apply the paginated decorator to your client. It's not done at the type level. Instead, you have to take your API client value, go into the particular client function that you want to paginate, and transform its ClientM action with the decorator in order to obtain a new API client. (If the client function has parameters, you'll need a bit more busywork to reach the ClientM action.)
Decorating the API client value is much easier if you use NamedRoutes (video) because then the client functions become name fields in a record, instead of being anonymous slots in and positional struture.
An example with named routes:
type PaginatedApi = NamedRoutes Foo

data Foo mode = Foo {
    firstContent :: 
        mode 
        :- "contents" 
        :> Get '[JSON] (Headers '[Header "Link" String] [Int]),
    extraContent :: 
        mode 
        :- "contents-extra" 
        :> Capture "page" Int 
        :> Get '[JSON] (Headers '[Header "Link" String] [Int])
  } deriving stock (Generic)

fooClient :: Client ClientM PaginatedApi
fooClient = client (Proxy @PaginatedApi)

fooClientDecorated :: Client ClientM PaginatedApi
fooClientDecorated = fooClient { firstContent = paginated fooClient.firstContent}


This repo https://github.com/danidiaz/servant-pagination-experiment contains a working example, includig a toy server.

It seems that the Link header used in the GitHub API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#using-link-headers has some structure beyond being single url. In that case, the paginated function would have to parse it using something like "http-link-header" https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-link-header

You're right about the different format in the GItHub API, but that can be solved using the http-link-header package. I adapted your example project to that format here: https://github.com/L7R7/haskell-incubator/tree/d69cca986d39fa23a45b0533082b19242626aa2f/servant-paginated-client. I didn't edit your answer because I think it's not directly related to my original question
